# How do I create a container on my site with subsections within it

Tags: html, css

So basically I am trying to create a page with a menu bar on top and then a main container that is divided into 2 sections at a ratio of 75% to 25% and on top of that the background of this container should stretch out infinitely horizontally.
Unfortunately I am somewhat lost at this point so this is my current code

```css
@font-face { font-family: UbuntuG; src: url('ubuntu-fonts/Ubuntu-L.ttf'); } 
body { background-color: #2d2d2d; }
h1 {
    color: white; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 30;
}
h2 {
    color: white; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 18;
}
p {
    color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #1d1d1d; border-spacing: 0; color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16; 
}
td  {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 48px;
    min-width:48px;
}
a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
   font-family: UbuntuG;
   font-size: 16;
      height:43px;
      line-height:43px;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

li {
    float: left; border-right: 2px solid white;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active {
    background-color: #00BFFF;
}

.left,
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 46%;
  padding: 2%;
}
.selector {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Radio</title>
    <meta content="??">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    <style>
        table, th, td { border: 5px solid white; border-spacing: 0; color: #1d1d1d; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16; }
        h1 { color: white; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 30; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div style="margin-top:-8;margin-right:-8;margin-left:-8"><ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Who are we?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul></div>
    <div style="background-color: black">
  <div class="right" align="right">
   <img height=300px width=300px style="border:0px solid white;" src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.apple.com%2Fdownloads%2Fdashboard%2Fstatus%2Fimages%2Fpolarclockwidget_20070723105852.jpg&f=1">
   <img height=300px width=300px style="border:0px solid white;" src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fa5.mzstatic.com%2Fus%2Fr30%2FPurple4%2Fv4%2Fae%2F41%2F4d%2Fae414d52-c726-ac67-27ea-02b8b56fcb37%2Ficon.png&f=1">
  </div>
  
  <span class="left" align="left">
   <p>PLAY NOW WIDGET</p>
  </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: whats the problem? where you set that 75%/25%? should it be horizontally divided or vertically? where is the background as i didn't see any bkg in your snippet

Comment: you might need to rephrase your goal to be more specific so people can help. For example, what do you mean "infinitely horizontally"? Do you want the element to fit any screen size or do you actually want some sort of scroll-able bar that you can scroll with if you have more item to fit in a screen. Also, the 75% split thing, might want to define which way you want the split.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of what i have understood from your question.
Your main top menu div is full width 100% and the content container with play now widet is 75% and img div is 25% with there container having some definite fixed width of 1200px(example width).. See the code below.

```css
@font-face { font-family: UbuntuG; src: url('ubuntu-fonts/Ubuntu-L.ttf'); } 
*{ box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;}
body { background-color: #2d2d2d; }
h1 {
    color: white; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 30;
}
h2 {
    color: white; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 18;
}
p {
    color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #1d1d1d; border-spacing: 0; color: white; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16; 
}
td  {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    height: 48px;
    min-width:48px;
}
a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
   font-family: UbuntuG;
   font-size: 16;
     
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1d1d1d;
}

li {
    float: left; border-right: 2px solid white;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active {
    background-color: #00BFFF;
}


.selector {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
/*Top full width container*/
.FullWidthContainer{ width:100%}
/*Content Container With max-width:1200px for example*/
.MainContainer{max-width:1200px; width:100%; margin: 0px auto; }
/* content containre divided in left-75% and right-25%}*/
.left{ width:75%; padding:2%; float:left;}
.right{ width:25%; padding:2%; float:right}
.right img{ width:100%}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Radio</title>
    <meta content="??">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    <style>
        table, th, td { border: 5px solid white; border-spacing: 0; color: #1d1d1d; font-family: Arial; font-size: 16; }
        h1 { color: white; font-family: UbuntuG; font-size: 30; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="FullWidthContainer"><ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Who are we?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
 </ul></div>
    <div style="background-color: black" class="FullWidthContainer">
      <div class="MainContainer">
          <span class="left" align="left">
   <p>PLAY NOW WIDGET</p>
  </span>
  <div class="right" align="right">
   <img height=300px width=300px style="border:0px solid white;" src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fimages.apple.com%2Fdownloads%2Fdashboard%2Fstatus%2Fimages%2Fpolarclockwidget_20070723105852.jpg&f=1">
   <img height=300px width=300px style="border:0px solid white;" src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fa5.mzstatic.com%2Fus%2Fr30%2FPurple4%2Fv4%2Fae%2F41%2F4d%2Fae414d52-c726-ac67-27ea-02b8b56fcb37%2Ficon.png&f=1">
  </div>
  
  
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but there a single issue with the menu bar that makes it look a little messed up.

Comment: I have fixed the above code and you are welcome . Please up vote my answer if its your solutions .. Thanks :)

Comment: Of course ty so much you have been up-voted but I got low reputation so not sure if it will show.